# VS Code for Mac - keyboard shortcut to comment a line no longer works

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio code on MacOS, version Version 1.25.0 and I'm working with HTML and CSS files.

The keyboard shortcut **"CMD+/"** doesn't comment out the current line. If I open the edit menu and select Toggle Line Comment, that works fine. I checked keyboard shortcuts and the keybinding for that command shows CMD+/. I tried to re-set it, but I couldn't re-add that keyboard shortcut.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem

Use ⌘K ⌘C to comment a line

Answer (score 0):

After commenting you need to add one more space then `CMD+/`